# "Invalid expression" setting 'foldtext', what is wrong?

Tags: vimscript, folding, set

I am trying to set `'foldtext'`, but it seems I misunderstand expressions, types, etc. of Vim fundamentally.

Why does the following refuse to work?

```
set foldtext=v:folddashes."TEST"
```

Whereas this works?

```
func Test()
    return "TEST"
endfunc
set foldtext=v:folddashes.Test()
```

I assume the `.` is not string concatenation in this context, but what is it instead?

Furthermore, why does Vim don't "recover" if `'foldtext'` is restored to default (or any other valid value)?

Comment: I further assume, that the value stored in `'foldtext'` is evaluated later on, but still don't see the point why a string does not work whereas a function returning a string works.

Comment: It does get more confusing, it has to be related to how the stuff is evaluated: `set foldtext=v:folddashes.'TEST'` **does** work.

Comment: From `:h expr6`: `For String concatenation ".." is preferred, since "." is ambiguous, it is also used for |Dict| member access and floating point numbers.` So always use either `v:folddashes . Test()`, or `v:folddashes..Test()` instead.